# where should create form with form helper in MVC, controller or model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, controller

where should create form with form helper in MVC, controller or model?

I mean where should I put these code:

```
$form = $this->get('formhelper');
$form->add_input('fname', ['type'=>'text']);
$form->add_input('lname', ['type'=>'text']);
```

Comment: Please read codeigniter tutorial guide. It will help solve all basic queries like this

Comment: I would create a class in a separate folder forms, and then call the form in your controller, for example $this->view->loginform  = new LoginForm();

Comment: @MHakvoort nice solution (I see this in symfony2 too), so after all this is not model responsibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely controller. Model is to include the database related codes.